# How to get rid of the blue highlight when opening a form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How would I get rid of this blue highlight when opening a form?

[image]

I am compiling in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: This is a Windows Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Form_Load` event handler change the text selection of the first text box like this

```
myTextBox.SelectionStart = 0
myTextBox.SelectionLength = 0
```

This is an alternative to calling the `Select` method as shown by Neolisk.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the TabIndex property manually from designer.

Answer (score 0):

Do `Select(0, 0)` on the first textbox in `Form_Load`, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  TextBox1.Select(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Official reference:

- [TextBox.Select @ MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)